Why I cannot add multiple prologs to slurm using path/*. slurm 21.08.5
I have 2 scripts that I want to set in PrologSlurmctld.
my slurm.conf reads:
PrologSlurmctld=/etc/slurm/prologslurmctld/*
But it doesnt work!
If I choose:
PrologSlurmctld=/etc/slurm/prologslurmctld/firstprolog.sh
It works!
If I choose:
PrologSlurmctld=/etc/slurm/prologslurmctld/secondprolog.sh
It works !
But not both with *. What am I missing, or slurm 21.08 has removed this option.
thanks


will be expanded to all elements separated by space.
But assigning variable value which contains spaces will causes error to bash.
A=value is ok, but A=value value is error.
Clarify what exactly you want to put to your variable


I have never worked with slurm, but are you sure that globbing is supposed to work with this parameter? Looking at the documentation for the conf file, I can't see that you could glob, and using a glob for this parameter does not sound meaningful to me either.

just below the tables you read that * is used -> https://slurm.schedmd.com/prolog_epilog.html. That's what I'm doing but doesn't work in my case. I will upgrade to version 24 to see if that resolves the problem
